# I can't see the USB hard drive on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, 20.04

On every other version of Ununtu I have installed, I plug in my USB hard drive when I want to look at the files on that drive.  I plug it in, hit the "open other locations" button in the "file" section and they are listed.  But 20.04 doesn't seem to act this way.  I have no idea where it is.  When I plug it in the drive light flickers for a few seconds and then stops, just like usual, but nothing shows up on the files section.

Comment: Have you looked in Disks?

Answer (score 0):

In 20.04 you should see the USB drive's name with the eject button on the left sidebar above the "+ Other Locations" button. It does not show up inside the "+ Other Locations" section.

Comment: On the left at the bottom is "Other Locations" and right above that is "trash".   There is no drive listed on that side.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, F*, do I feel like an idiot!  I had put a brand new HDD into that USB connection and had forgotten to take it out and put the old one in, so OF COURSE it didn't show up.  Once I put the old drive (that I had wanted to look at) into the USB connection, it showed up very quickly.  Oops!  As usual, no problem is bigger than stupidity. :-)